# lisp iterative or recursive?

Tags: recursion, iteration, lisp

```
Given: (cont-frac (lambda (i) 1.0)
                  (lambda (i) 1.0)
                   k), 
        d and k is a function themselves.


Solutions 
    -iterative:
        (define (cont-frac-iter n d k)
          (define (iter i result)
            (if (= 0 i)
                result
                (iter (sub1 i) (/ (n i) (+ result (d i))))))
          (iter (sub1 k) (/ (n k) (d k))))
    -recursive:
        (define (cont-frac-recur n d k)
          (define (recur i)
            (if (= k i)
                (/ (n i) (d i))
                (/ (n i) (+ (d i) (recur (+ 1 i))))))
          (recur 1))
```

Question: given solutions are correct, **both recursive and iterative approach have same outcome**, but why the recursive solution count as recursive? what is the difference between them both?

Comment: **procedure** is not the same as **process**

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about *functions*, any function that calls itself in its body can be said *recursive*, so in your example both the functions `iter` and `recur` calls themselves and for this reason are recursive. A function that in its body does not call (neither directly nor indirectly) itself or a part of itself is not recursive.

On the other hand, if a recursive function can be *executed* in a way similar to a loop (like a while or a for loop, for instance), its execution is called iterative. This is possible at least for the *tail-recursive* functions: i.e. functions where the *last* instruction in every branch of the body (the “tail”) is a call to itself (like `inter` in your example, while for `recur` there is a branch in which the last instruction is a `\`). This is because the execution of the function (in general the code produced by some “smart” compiler) mimics that of a kind of loop, without requiring additional memory at each iteration like in the case of non tail-recursive functions (or “true” recursive functions). So the *execution process* is an iterative process (and somebody calls improperly the function an “iterative” function).